# Redirect users to different pages based on their login informations

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi is it possible to redirect users to a certain page based on authentication?

I am using this code but it redirects all users to the same page rather i want redirect User X to Page X, User Y to Page Y and extra.

```
   add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');

   function wc_login_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
        $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/pageX/';
        return $redirect_to;
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
function wc_login_redirect( ) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/page'.get_current_user_id().'/';
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

Or you can change the logic to pick pageX based on userX value if you need that.

Comment: Thanks @veta how can i change the logic to change Page X based on UserX?

Comment: It depends on what logic do you require. If X = the ID of the user (a number) than the code above will redirect the user to the pageX (eg. page34). If you need other logic you need to map the user id to the page somehow: create an array, or database table to store [user_id, page] values...

Comment: i get something like http://exmple.com/0/?  itried `add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
 
function wc_login_redirect( ) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.get_current_user_id().'/';
    return $redirect_to;
}`  and i created a page same as a username. You gave me a right solution if gets the username

Comment: I modified it a little bit and worked `add_filter('woocommerce_login_redirect', 'wc_login_redirect');
 
function wc_login_redirect( ) {

$user_info = get_userdata(1);
if ($user_id == 0) {
    $redirect_to = 'http://example.com/'.$user_info->user_login.'/';
    return $redirect_to;
}
}`

Comment: Yes, you need the proper function to get the username, the original requirement was not clear to me, sorry